# Android tablet with 10+ inch screen, 2 or 4 gb ram, GPS and 3/4G recommendation

Tags: android, tablet

So I wanna buy a tablet that is the closest to these specs:

- 10 to 11.6 inch screen
- Android 5.1 or above. Dual boot tablets (with ability to run Windows as well) are also okay
- At least 2 GB of RAM
- GPS
- SIM slot for 3G or 4G LTE
- Under $200 (if it is possible) or the closest option

I consider any brand, both well-known and lesser prominent, but the device should have at least some footprint, e.g. some reviews, so totally no-name options from Ali aren't a good option.